# Programmatically adding items to relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout tha has the following xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/date_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/navigation_bar_layout"
    android:background="@color/light_gray"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detaildatetextview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see it already has a textview in it. at some place in my code I need to add an image programmatically before the text view. That means firstly image will be displayed and then the text view. But Image gets shown when I execute the code and text view does not. Please help me out of this. My implementation is as follows:

```
image  = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
image.setId(0);
dateText = (TextView) dateBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.detaildatetextview);
dateText.setText("Dummy text");
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) dateBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, dateText.getId());                       
String icon = "drawable/"+ path;
icon = icon.replaceAll("-", "_");
icon = icon.toLowerCase();
int imageResource = this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(icon, null,this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
image.setImageResource(imageResource);
dateBarLayout.addView(image);
```

I don't know where I am going wrong..please help me getting out of this. Thanks in advance...:-)

Comment: did you want to show image and top of the image the text ?

Comment: No, I want show firstly image and then text...in simple words from left to right image and then comes the text.

Comment: @UsamaSarwar Please see my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set layout params to the view is being added, to place it in relative layout, else it will overlap, left-top view in the layout, so instead of addView(View) use [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) method to add the view to layout. So change your code to following:

```
image  = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    image.setId(0);

    dateText = (TextView) dateBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.detaildatetextview);

    dateText.setText("Dummy text");



        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) dateBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, dateText.getId());

        String icon = "drawable/"+ path;
        icon = icon.replaceAll("-", "_");
            icon = icon.toLowerCase();

        int imageResource = this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(icon, null,this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());

        image.setImageResource(imageResource);
                    dateBarLayout.addView(image, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below Code into your java file after `setcontentview(R.layout.main);` , it will solve your problem.

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
RelativeLayout dateBarLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.date_bar_layout);
TextView dateText = (TextView) dateBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.detaildatetextview);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, dateText.getId());
image.setLayoutParams(params);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
dateBarLayout.addView(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/Rl"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>



 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:onClick="addAddbutton"
    android:text="add"
    android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


mainActivity.java

package com.example.textboxonclick;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private RelativeLayout Rl;
private EditText myEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
ln = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Rl);

 }
 public void addAddbutton(View v) {
 myEditText = new EditText(this);
 Rl.addView(myEditText);
}
}
```

Comment: Please add some text to your answer. What did you change in the code to fix the problem in the question? Can you explain in a few words why that is necessary?

Comment: Dear this is very simple,we have a button inside relative layout on that button click simply add  a editText in relative Layout.